# Images Have Different Vertical & Horizontal Resolutions in PDF

Tags: images, pdf, resolution, image-quality

I recently got a `PDF` from a client that includes several images. For some strange reason, the vertical and horizontal resolution of each individual image differs. Some of them differ by a huge degree. Here's the specs of one of the image in question...

[image: Document Information]

`47 by 216 pixels`

`51.84 by 11.28 points`

`65.278 by 1378.69 pixels per inch`

I noticed this while doing pre-print prep and was a little curious. I've seen the h-res and v-res differ by a small percentage before, but not to this degree.

What actions could result in an image with these properties?

Did the graphic artist simply have to stretch an existing image to fit the overall PDF layout, resulting in fewer pixels on the stretched axis?

Comment: Nobody? Give me some guesses..anything...lol. :)

Comment: I'd **guess** that yes the image was "squished" or "stretched" in a layout application (like Indesign) to fit the area. Since layout apps will not recalculate ppi when a placed image dimensions are altered, the pixels get distorted to fit the new boundaries of the image.

Comment: i've seen this before on pdf's i have saved back to smallest size. it could be something to do with the save process in acrobat. weird one!

Comment: Stephen, can you explain what you mean by 'saved back to smallest size'? Do you just mean optimizing it essentially? Thanks.